# How to add a pdf file to blob container on a HTTP trigger (POST) , with the pdf in the request body

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I want to add the file into blob container of my azure account on a http trigger(POST), here is the functions.json file:

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": [
       
        "post"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "$return"
    },
    {
      "type": "blob",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "outputBlob",
      "path": "outcontainer/{filename}",
      "connection": "********"
    }
  ]
}
```

and below is the init.py code:

```
import logging

import azure.functions as func


def main(req: func.HttpRequest ,  outputBlob: func.Out[bytes]) -> func.HttpResponse:
    try:
        
        pdf_file = req.files.get("pdf")
        logging.info("got pdf ")
        
        if pdf_file:
            pdf_content = pdf_file.read()
            logging.info("READ pdf ")
            logging.info(f"{pdf_file.filename}")
           
            blob_path = "outcontainer/" + pdf_file.filename 
            logging.info("set path pdf ")
           
            outputBlob.set(pdf_content)
            logging.info("uploaded pdf ")
            return func.HttpResponse(f"PDF uploaded successfully", status_code=200)
        else:
            return func.HttpResponse("No PDF file provided in the request", status_code=400)
    except Exception as e:
        return func.HttpResponse(f"An error occurred: {str(e)}", status_code=500)
```

I am getting a error that `System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Functions.HttpTrigger1. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: No value for named parameter 'filename'.`

Removing the {filename} in function.json and replacing it with a constant keyword , running the code this way do add an item in blob storage but its not of a pdf format and also item keeps on uploading with same name that is replacing the old item. I want the item added to be of the same format and name as the original item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With below Code  able to add a pdf file to blob container on a HTTP trigger (POST) , with the pdf in the request body

- install `pip install azure-storage-blob azure-functions`

```py
import  logging
import  azure.functions  as  func
from  azure.storage.blob  import  BlobServiceClient
def  main(req:  func.HttpRequest)  ->  func.HttpResponse:
logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
try:
req_body = req.get_json()
local_path = req_body.get('local_path')
except  Exception  as  e:
return  func.HttpResponse(
"Invalid request body",
status_code=400
) 
storage_connection_string = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;A"
container_name = "hellocont"
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(storage_connection_string)
container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container_name)
blob_name = local_path.split("/")[-1]
blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client(blob_name)
with  open(local_path,  "rb")  as  pdf_file:
blob_client.upload_blob(pdf_file)
return  func.HttpResponse(f"PDF uploaded successfully as '{blob_name}'",  status_code=200)
```

- With [function.json](https://i.imgur.com/De7HXSQ.png)

[image]

[image]

```py
import os
import azure.functions as func
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    try:
        req_body = req.get_json()
        connect_str = req_body.get('connect_str')
        container_name = req_body.get('container_name')
        file_path = req_body.get('file_path')
        file_str = req_body.get('file_str')
        
        # Use a relative path for Azure Functions
        local_path = os.path.join('temp', file_path)
        
        blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connect_str)
        container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container_name)
        blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client(file_path)
        blob_client.upload_blob(file_str, overwrite=True)
        
        return func.HttpResponse(f"File uploaded to blob storage account: {file_path}")
    except Exception as e:
        return func.HttpResponse(f"An error occurred: {str(e)}", status_code=500)
```

- **With Azure function URL:**

[image]